# Спарсить ссылку из BBCode

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, bbcode

Нужно вытащить из текста первую ссылку, сделал такой вариант:

```
preg_match('/\[link=(.*)\].*\[\/link\]/i', $data['text'], $url_type);
```

не знаю, как добавить проверку `http(s)://` вначале и если конструкция `[link=(.*)\].*\[\/link\]` не найдена, то искать в `[link](.*)[/link]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задачу в принципе можно решать разными путями, например поискать сначала одной регуляркой, если не получилось то другой. Но мне захотелось попробовать сделать универсальную.

Кстати, при приведенном в вопросе примере одна ошибка: `.*` *"жадная"* операция и если в строке будет `[link=aaa] xx [/link] mm [/link]`, то в подстроку будет захвачено все, до последнего `[/link]` и итоговый url получится `aaa] xx [/link] mm`. Что бы такого не происходило всего лишь надо сказать звездочке, что бы она не была *"жадной"*, добавив вопросительный знак: `.*?`

В приведенном ниже коде применяются гораздо более сложные конструкции, описания которых можно найти наример в [википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F).

```
preg_match('/\[link(?|(?:=(https?:\/\/.*?) *\].*?)|(?:\](https?:\/\/.*?)|.*?)) *\[\/link\]/i',
  $data['text'], $match);

if(isset($match[1]) && $match[1]): $url_type=$match[1]; endif;
```

Приведенный пример реагирует на ссылки http и https, ссылки на ftp в заданном вопросе искать не предлагалось. Код даст позитивный результат *только* в случае правильной конструкции `[link] [/link]`. Т.е. если в первый тег именно `[link]` без других символов внутри скобок - то будет взята http ссылка между тегами. Либо, если ссылка внутри первого тега и перед ней обязательно стоит знак 'равно'. Конструкции `[link некорректная-ссылка]http://www.ru[/link]` считаются не корректными и ссылка изнутри тега не достается.